# How to serialize ObjectId to JSON?

Tags: java, json, mongodb, jackson, jongo

I want to serialize ObjectId of my `Product` class to JSON. I got the following JSON:

```
[{"name":"Play for Java: Covers Play 2","type":"Book","company":"Manning Publications","price":30.0,"imagePath":"public/images/play-for-java.png","rating":4.5,"category":"Computer","author":"Nicolas Leroux","publicationDate":1396224000000,"numPage":320,"_id":539da7a6370882f10d5c2777}]
```

You can notice that the `"_id"` didn't be properly serialized, it should be `"539da7a6370882f10d5c2777"` (with double quotes) and not just `539da7a6370882f10d5c2777`.

Therefore, I have tried to implement my own `ObjectIdSerializer` as following:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;

public class ObjectIdSerializer extends JsonSerializer<ObjectId> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(ObjectId value, JsonGenerator jsonGen,SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {
        jsonGen.writeString(value.toString());
    }
}
```

It gave me the different error: `java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.bson.types.ObjectId (through reference chain: models.Book["_id"])`

Here are my `Product` class and `Book` class:

**Product.java**

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use= JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS,property="_class")
public class Product {
    @ObjectId @Id
    @JsonSerialize(using = ObjectIdSerializer.class)
    protected String id;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    protected String name;
    @JsonProperty("type")
    protected String type;
    @JsonProperty("description")
    protected String description;
    @JsonProperty("company")
    protected String company;
    @JsonProperty("price")
    protected float price;
    @JsonProperty("imagePath")
    protected String imagePath;
    @JsonProperty("imageName")
    protected String imageName;
    @JsonProperty("rating")
    protected float rating;

    public Product() {
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    // Getters and setters
   ...
```

**Book.java**

```
public class Book extends Product{

    @JsonProperty("category")
    private String category;
    @JsonProperty("author")
    private String author;
    @JsonProperty("publicationDate")
    private Date publicationDate;
    @JsonProperty("numPage")
    private int numPage;

    public Book() {
    }
    // Getters and setters   
   ...
```

Can you help me figure it out how can I properly serialize the `ObjectId` to JSON?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like Jackson has been customized to serialize the string id field in a special way. That is probably a part of the integration with `org.bson` library.

The problem is that your deserializer is parametrized by the `ObjectId` type instead of `String` or plain `Object`. Try to change it as follows and also remove the `@ObjectId` annotation from the field declaration. Here is an example:

```
public class ObjectIdSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator jsonGen,SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        jsonGen.writeString(value.toString());
    }
}
```

You may also consider adopting [the Jackson-Jongo provider class](https://gist.github.com/yamsellem/3155831) to fix the object id serialization for all the classes.

Comment: Thanks for you response. It's almost perfect except the serialized _id is a little bit strange, "_id":"\"539df7793708be9becea990e\"". Moreover, the `_id` in my MongoDB has changed from `"_id" : ObjectId("539e06e03708a8e88421cf6d")` to `"_id":"539e06e03708a8e88421cf6d"`.  

Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: Can you try to remove the ObjectId annotation? I have updated my answer with regards to it.

Comment: It worked like a charm! Could you explain a bit why it does work by removing the `ObjectId`? Without the `ObjectId`, Is there any effect to my class in the future ?

Comment: I wonder what would happen if you just remove the ObjectId annotation and the JsonDeserialize?

Comment: I got `"_id" : "539e9c70ccf270420d3e96a8"`, however, I don't know if it is good to keep the `_id` as string instead of `ObjectId`.

Comment: I am new to Spring. Where should I add this class? Does it require @Configuration annotation? Thanks.